# Hadoop not using config files?

Tags: hadoop, configuration, directory, hdfs

I'm deploying Hadoop at work and I've been troubleshooting some days. Yesterday it was working perfectly but today something strange is happening.

I have hadoop.tmp.dir set in core-site.xml as well as other directories for HDFS (datanode, namenode and secondarynamenode in hdfs-site.xml). But today, when I format the FS it's creating all the files in /tmp and not in /usr/local/hadoop/tmp which is the one I have configured.

```
$ bin/hdfs namenode -format
[...]    
INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/dfs/name has been successfully formatted.
[...]
```

*core-site.xml*

```
<property>
      <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>                
      <value>/usr/local/hadoop/tmp</value>
</property>
```

*hdfs-site.xml*

```
   <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/hdfs/namenode</value>
   </property>

   <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/hadoop/hdfs/secondname</value>
   </property>

   <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/hadoop/hdfs/datanode</value>
   </property>
```

Anyone has any clue about what's happening?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're deploying Hadoop, I suggest you use Apache Ambari rather than editing XML yourself. Also, what is your `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` environment variable set to?

Comment: It's not set as it uses automatically $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop (which is correct and HADOOP_HOME set correctly)

Comment: Are you sure those variables are set for the same user account starting or running the hadoop commands? Because it seems you're still getting the default property values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what was wrong and it was really embarrassing. My hadoop user had bash as default sh but wasn't loading correctly the profile until I explicitly did "bash" on command line.
Saw it with printenv command.

Answer (score 0):

make sure this directory exists and have enough permission

give the path as `file:///usr/local/hadoop/tmp`

Comment: We tried Ambari, but doesn't work as it uses default directories for installation and /usr is read only because of work policy.
Another problem we have with Ambari is that this project is for university labs and we need to control more than one cluster